# Images loaded after $(document).ready in webkit browsers' refresh

Tags: jquery, webkit, page-refresh, document-ready

I have a case where it seems that the contents of $(document).ready are being executed before the page is actually loaded. This happens when the page is **REFRESHED** in **WEBKIT** browsers. What's going on with that?

It's messing with my offset() calculations because the calculation is made before all of the CSS is applied.

Comment: That is, you reload while the page hasn't finished loading yet?

Comment: I can't tell without seeing your code, but if you are processing images `$(document).ready` *may* start executing **before** the images are fully loaded...if this is the case use `$(window).load` instead!

Comment: Thanks ifaour $(window).load solved my problem!! You are awesome!! Still curious why refresh would behave different than the initial load...I'll look more into it.

Comment: cool, I've posted it as an answer! :-)

Comment: Great question! I might never have found my answer if you hadn't posted it; thanks @ifaour for the alternative which worked for me as well. SideDishStudio, please update your question's title so that future persons stumped by this can find the answer easier. Suggested title: `Images loaded after $(document).ready in webkit browsers' refresh`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are processing images, `$(document).ready` may start executing before the images are fully loaded...if this is the case use `$(window).load` instead!

Answer (score 4):

`$(document).ready()` is invoked when the DOM is fully loaded.  Now that doesn't necessarily mean your page is fully loaded - e.g. background images in the CSS may still be loading.

Comment: makes sense, but are there any fundamental differences between a page load and a page refresh that would create different results in the way the offset is calculated? Is it just the timing of the load due to caching or something more procedural?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems with refreshing a page (especially with Chrome), and I've found that by simply moving the CSS link *above* the script, so that it loads first, resolved all issues.