# jQuery Code Only Fires On Hard Refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error, facebook-iframe, page-refresh

The XFBML version of the Facebook Registration plugin only loads HTTPS. I need it to load HTTP so my form does not call a security error mismatch between domains.

I wrote this code to get the SRC and rewrite it with out HTTPS

It works fine on the first load, however on Chrome and Safari it only loads the first time and on HARD refreshes. It does not load on standard reloads or by pressing "enter" on the address bar. Here is the code

```
$(window).load(function () {
          // Replace HTTPS with HTTP when frame has loaded
       $(".subscribe iframe").each(function(){
        var source = $(this).attr("src");
        //alert(source);
        var sourceNew = source.replace("https", "http"); // change https to http
        alert(sourceNew);
        $(this).attr("src", sourceNew); 
    }); 
});
```

I have .HTACCESS set to disable server cache

```
<Files *>
Header set Cache-Control: "private, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0"
Header set Expires: 0
Header set Pragma: no-cache
</Files>
```

What is causing this to not fire reliably? Thanks

Comment: You should check if your server config has any particular cache settings.

Comment: HTACCESS is already set to disable cache. Weird thing is that on FireFox, it loads 100% of the time. So that makes me believe it wouldn't be a server-issue but rather a browser issue.

Comment: Why are you using `$(window).load`, and not just `$(function(){…})`?

Comment: I need to wait until all the iframes are loaded, which are programatically inserted by Facebook JS SDK, so that I can then grab the source. Otherwise it's Undefined.

Comment: I had similar problems in non-FF browsers until I set the "Expires" directive for htaccess cache in one case. Have you set this (to a past date...)?

Comment: @CBroe: check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284986/images-loaded-after-document-ready-in-webkit-browsers-refresh/5285268#5285268). BTW, I'm not sure if you are allowed to alter the Registration plugin resources. This might be a violation of Facebook policies.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Expires directive in htaccess to:

```
Header set Expires "Mon, 01 Jan 1990 01:00:00 GMT"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<body onload="replacehttps()">` and then change

```
$(window).load(function () {
```

to

```
function replacehttps(){
```

and don't forget to change the end of your function block from `});` to `};`